# Rails 5 - Query records with a uniq attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 5 and Postgresql. 
This question has been answered for previous versions of Rails (including Rails 4, using distinct, uniq, etc, but none of it worked for me with Rails 5 since they've been depreciated).

I have a `Upload` model, which has a `uuid` attribute. 
I want to fetch records having a different `uuid` without using `uniq` from enumerables.

Here is my original query:

```
Upload.includes(:user, product: [:catalog]).where(file_type: "product_attachment", product_id: nil, user_id: current_user.id))
```

I get errors when adding `distinct` or `select` (and it seems like those methods are often used to return only one attribut from the model while I need the whole object here).

Any idea on how to achieve this in Rails 5 ?

Edit with sample data:

Uploads:

```
id: 1 
uuid: 8e8fece82b6b1368ab6f21852c625e85718d210e

id: 2
uuid: 842e7650b4bba97f097d9cf57f47d8160086b7cd

id: 3
uuid: 8e8fece82b6b1368ab6f21852c625e85718d210e
```

Uploads 1 and 3 have the same uuid, so the expected result would only contain the uploads with id 1 and 2 (which have a distinct uuid).

Comment: Can you create an minimal example of the data in the tables and the expected result? You can use select like so Upload.select(`DISTINCT ON(uploads.uuid), uploads.*)` or use something like a lateral join.

Comment: @max just edited with a more concrete example

Comment: @max I already tried a select like your query, I get this error: 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT ON(uploads.uuid), uploads.* FROM "uploads

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want `Upload` with minimum `id` for every duplicate group of `uuid`,

```
Upload.includes(:user, product: [:catalog]).where(file_type: "product_attachment", product_id: nil, user_id: current_user.id)).
       where(id: Upload.group(:uuid).select("min(id)"))
```

To break it down, this `where` clause filters all the `Upload` with duplicate `uuid` except the one with `min` `id`

```
where(id: Upload.group(:uuid).select("min(id)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group;` it gives you all distinct records without using uniq:

```
ABC.group(:uuid)
```